# spring-cloud-data flow : How to ship stream logs to kibana?

Tags: logging, kibana, spring-cloud-stream, filebeat, spring-cloud-dataflow

spring-cloud-dataflow : How to ship stream logs to kibana ? is there a way we can ship all the container logs from Spring Cloud Data Flow server itself ?

If not, how do we setup file beat for a stream.